# What was the behavior toward farming pigs (or other "abominable" animals)?

Tags: plants-and-animals

As far as I know, since very old times and until the time of Jesus, pigs were "abominable" animals, so they couldn't be eaten.

Leviticus 7:21 KJV

> Moreover the soul that shall touch any unclean thing, as the uncleanness of man, or any unclean beast, or any abominable unclean thing, and eat of the flesh of the sacrifice of peace offerings, which pertain unto the LORD, even that soul shall be cut off from his people.

Leviticus 11:7 KJV

> And the swine, though he divide the hoof, and be clovenfooted, yet he cheweth not the cud; he is unclean to you.

Nevertheless, it turns out that pigs were widely farmed as in the Parable of the Lost Son.

Luke 15:15 NIV

> So he went and hired himself out to a citizen of that country, who sent him to his fields to feed pigs.

What was the actual behavior of people toward those animals? Were they farmed or not? If they were, what for?

Comment: The parable is about a 'far' country. Luke 15:13. That is, not Israel. Which is a main feature of the parable that the son had forsaken so much, yet was received back again. In that 'far country' : yes, they would have eaten ham. See also the Gadarene swine on the far side of the sea of Galilee - 'Galilee of the Gentiles'.

Comment: A minor detail, but while "Matthew" has the miracle of the "Porcine Lemmings" occurring in Gadara, both Mark and Luke have it occurring in Gerasa/Jerash in what is now Jordan. So "Matthew" seems to have misread "Mark":  

https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6458-gadarenes

Comment: I don't know about ancient Israel, but even today it isn't unusual to raise swine for reasons other than slaughter. They can be used for garbage and sewage disposal, preventing disease in other animals, tilling the soil, etc. ([4 Reasons to Add Pigs to Your Homestead](https://thriftyhomesteader.com/4-reasons-to-add-pigs-to-your-homestead/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hebrew word שֶׁקֶץ (sheh'-kets) can indeed mean "abomination," but here it refers to a food that is not kosher. For this reason contemporary translators sometimes use the term "unclean thing." (see NIV, NRSV) Some use adjectives such as "loathsome." In any case, not all "unclean" animals are "abominable." The horse is a good example. Israelites rode them and used them to drive chariots but did not eat them. So an animal that might be שֶׁקֶץ as food was not necessarily an "abomination" per se.

Regarding pig farming, Israelites generally refrained from it because pigs were not kosher. This is evident not only because of the biblical prohibition but also from the [archaeological record](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236610451_Pig_Husbandry_in_Iron_Age_Israel_and_Judah_New_Insights_Regarding_the_Origin_of_the_Taboo). But we do not know how universally the biblical taboo was enforced, just as we don't know how many ancient Jews kept the Sabbath strictly. Indeed some archaeological evidence indicates that [the practice of pig farming was not unknown](https://www.timesofisrael.com/this-little-piggy-went-to-jerusalem-2700-years-ago-raising-some-questions/), even in Jerusalem:

> Although pork consumption was clearly not preferred in the region of
> Judah, the presence of an articulated skeleton of a small pig seems to
> indicate that not only was pork consumed in small amounts… but that
> pigs were raised for this purpose in the capital of Judah. This has
> far-reaching implications for understanding the pork-taboo often
> attributed to ancient Israel and Judah.

To this we may add that there were many non-Jews living in the area of Jesus' ministry in the Galilee. One village might be Jewish, while another might be [Syrophoenician, Greek or mixed](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/pdf/10.1086/474135).

**Conclusion**: pig farming was rarer in ancient Israel and Judah than in neighboring countries. However, the fact that pigs were not kosher does not mean that the animal itself was an "abomination." There is evidence that some residents of ancient Judah did raise pigs. In the area of the Galilee, there must have been quite a few pig farmers, though probably not so many Jewish ones. In the Prodigal Son's case, he was not only feeding pigs, but probably working for a Gentile.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Luke 15:15 in context provides insight.

> 11 And he said, “There was a man who had two sons. 12 And the younger of them said to his father, ‘Father, give me the share of property that is coming to me.’ And he divided his property between them. 13 Not many days later, **the younger son gathered all he had and took a journey into a far country**, and there he squandered his property in reckless living. 14 And when he had spent everything, a severe famine arose in that country, and he began to be in need. 15 So he went and hired himself out to one of the citizens of that country, who sent him into his fields to feed pigs. 16 And he was longing to be fed with the pods that the pigs ate, and no one gave him anything.

In verse 13 the younger son "took a journey into a far country". Somewhere far from Judea. In the far country is where pigs were farmed.

Pigs were not farmed in Judea during the time of Jesus.
The behavior of the people of Israel toward pigs was to avoid them like the plague.

The point of the story is that the behavior of the younger son resulted in the most horrible consequences possible - taking care of pigs, who ate better than he did. In spite of all this the father stood ready to take him back but the older brother was bitter.

Reading chapter 15 starting in verse 1 gives us insight.

> 1 Now the tax collectors and sinners were all drawing near to hear him. 2 And the Pharisees and the scribes grumbled, saying, “This man receives sinners and eats with them.”

The younger son represents "tax collectors, and sinners". The older son represents "Pharisees and the scribes".